# Not able to add migration and updating database in dotnet core ef

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I am using generic **DesignTimeDbContextFactory** in Dotnet core 2.2.1 version for database.

I am trying to add migration for which, a class created under the migration folder but didn't reflect the changes in **UP** and **Down** and also in ContextModelSnapShot file.

if I try with dropping ContextModelSnapShot, then changing reflected. but the issue here is it will build a table but also dropping the table  in **DOWN**.

Can anyone help me to come out through this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is the previous changes file is exists which already did by the previous developer who is working on it. I just temporary remove that file from the migration folder for that particular context as i have multiple contexts in my app and try to do migration will work for me. it was conflicting with the previous files.